# If $\alpha^3-\alpha+1=0$ then $\sqrt{3}\neq a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c$ for $a$, $b$, $c\in \mathbf{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, roots, radicals

Im stuck on the following:

> Let $f(x) =x^3-x+1$ and let $\alpha$ be a real root of $f$. Prove that $$\sqrt{3} \neq a\alpha^2 +b\alpha +c$$ for any $a$, $b$, $c\in \mathbf{Q}.$

I am preparing for a prelim and this is in the ring/field theory section. Yet it looks mostly like a number theory question. I do not even know how to begin. All I can figure out is that $\alpha^3=\alpha-1.$ I also tried squaring both sides of $\sqrt{3}=a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c$ and got to $$3=a^2\alpha^4+2ab\alpha^3+(b^2+2ac)\alpha^2+2bc\alpha+c^2 =a^2\alpha(\alpha-1)+2ab(\alpha-1)+(b^2+2ac)\alpha^2+2bc\alpha+c^2$$ At which point I stopped because I didnt think a prelim would have us deal with this sort of mess.

Any hints or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

Comment: @anomaly How would I justify that $[\mathbf{Q}(\alpha):\mathbf{Q}]=3$?

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson $[Q(\alpha):Q]$ is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $Q[x]$

Comment: @IrbidMath true, now I would have to show that $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha.$

Comment: Hint: Put in $a/b$ for $\alpha$ and look modulo $2$

Comment: Wait hang on. So you know that $\alpha^3 = \alpha-1$ and $3 = p(\alpha)$ for some quadratic polynomial $p$. Simplifying these gives you that $q(\alpha) = p'(\alpha)=0$ where $q'(\alpha) = \alpha^3-\alpha-1$ and $p'(\alpha) = p(\alpha)-3$ is some quadratic polynomial. Thus, $\alpha$ is a root of $p'$ and $q'$, and therefore it must be a root of their gcd as polynomials. At this point showing that $q'$ is irreducible is sufficient as done in the answer below, which would mean that such a gcd equals $1$, contradicting the existence of non-trivial $p$. No ring-field theory etc. needed.

Comment: Not placing this as an answer because I don't have the time, someone else borrow it please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to finalise what's been commented. Checking irreducibility of $f$ is maybe easier than you think!

$f$ is cubic, checking irreducibility amounts to checking no rational roots exist. Were $f$ reducible over $\Bbb Q$, then by a well-known principle - $f$ is a monic integer polynomial - it would reduce into monic integer factors. In particular, the mysterious root $n$ would have to be an integer and $1=nk$ where $k$ is also integer. Of course $n=\pm1$ is forced, but you can check these aren't roots. It follows that $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, and from there that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=\mathrm{deg}\,f=3$.

As $2\nmid3$ no intermediate quadratic extension can exist; $\sqrt{m}\in\Bbb Q(\alpha)\iff\sqrt{m}\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: `\mid` for the divisibility symbol fixes the correct spacing automatically. And the `\not` modifier is designed to interact horizontal things (like $=$ and $\equiv$ and $\cong$) and clashes with the vertical bar. Thus the `\nmid` command for "does not divide".

Comment: @Arthur Thank you!